# how to execute series of sqlcommand at once in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In my window application I need to execute a series of sqlcommands. There is no problem if all sqlcommands execute successfully, but when 2nd or 3rd command get error, it create big problem to me because command 1st is executed but 2nd and 3rd are not executed. Here I want either all commands executed or none. my code is follows:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + textBox8.Text + "_stock]("
                        + "[date] [date] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,"
                        + "[openingstock] [int] NOT NULL,"
                        + "[receipt] [int] NOT NULL,"
                        + "[totalstock] [int] NOT NULL,"
                        + "[sell] [int] NOT NULL,"
                        + "[closingstock] [int] NOT NULL,"
                        + ") ON [PRIMARY]", connectionsql);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();                  

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into " + textBox8.Text + "_stock values(@date,0,0,0,0,0)", connectionsql);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", dateTimePicker3.Value);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into rate values ('" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "_stock','" + double.Parse(textBox7.Text) + "','" + comboBox4.SelectedItem + "')", connectionsql);
                    int z = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd2.Dispose();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Use `TransactionScope`... see example at bottom of the [MSDN page].(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transactions` to do this. I mean something like:

```
transaction.BeginTransaction();
try{
    // your commands here
    transaction.CommitTransaction(); // commit after all commands
} catch (Exception){
    // if exception, rollback
    transaction.RollbackTransaction();
}
```

For further information, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx

**IMPORTANT:** Consider using [parameterized  queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I am not able to use transaction, it is not displayed in intellisense. which assembly I should use for this?

Comment: In the link there's a full example, take a look at it. I think you can do it with the example. I've updated the link to EN.

Answer (score 1):

**Transactions** are the way to go. In your case:

```
using (SqlConnection connectionsql= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connectionsql.Open();

    SqlTransaction transaction;

    // Start a local transaction.
    transaction = connectionsql.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + textBox8.Text + "_stock]("
        + "[date] [date] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,"
        + "[openingstock] [int] NOT NULL,"
        + "[receipt] [int] NOT NULL,"
        + "[totalstock] [int] NOT NULL,"
        + "[sell] [int] NOT NULL,"
        + "[closingstock] [int] NOT NULL,"
        + ") ON [PRIMARY]", connectionsql);

    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() <1) // no table created
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
    else // no error
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into " + textBox8.Text + "_stock values(@date,0,0,0,0,0)", connectionsql);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", dateTimePicker3.Value);

        if (cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() < 1) // no row inserted
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        else // no error
        {
            cmd1.Dispose();

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into rate values ('" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "_stock','" + double.Parse(textBox7.Text) + "','" + comboBox4.SelectedItem + "')", connectionsql);
            int z = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (z < 1) // no row inserted
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            else // no error
            {
                transaction.Commit(); // everything was OK, you can commit the results
            }           
            cmd2.Dispose(); 
        }
        cmd1.Dispose();
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I've use your code, but still a problem is there. I get an error that require ExecuteNonQuery() after first command. I think, Because transaction commit at last so table is not created so II command can not fill the entries in that. sorry if I am wrong, I don't know about transaction.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. If the table won't create, the transaction will be rolled back. Every step has to finish, for the code to proceed. It's like you wanted - all or nothing. If you get any errors please write in which line exactly and what does the error say exactly.